# How do I vertically align placeholder text in textarea?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align the placeholder text in textarea (textbox). I am using textarea instead of text input because I need to use multiple lines.

```css
.textbox1 { 
  width: 440px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textbox1"name="mytextarea"placeholder="Name"></textarea>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gICqd

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "vertically align" - do you mean in the middle, top, or bottom? I'm presuming you mean middle.

Comment: Also, how many lines do you think you need? You only have 2 as-is. If you can set rows to 3 you can easily align the text with line feeds, I just posted an answer explaining...

Comment: The problem with other answers IMO is that when you start typing the text is still aligned in the middle. Maybe that's what OP meant but I thought this is just supposed to be the placeholder text, not the entered text as well. Need more clarification...

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using **padding-top** which will increase the height of the textarea and extra space down use the **line-height** here is a sample, you can vary the line-height.

```
textarea::placeholder {
line-height: 90px;
```

}

you can also use *transform* property like this:

```
   textarea::placeholder {
transform: translateY(-20px);
```

}

Comment: The transform seems cool, but it didn't seem to work in firefox.

Comment: It works also in firefox now. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

One option is to use `line-height`:

```
.textbox1 { 
    width: 440px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

```css
.textbox1 { 
    width: 440px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textbox1"name="mytextarea"placeholder="Name"></textarea>
```

You can also use `padding` to control the position of the text.

Here's an example using `padding-top`

```css
.textbox1 { 
    width: 440px;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textbox1"name="mytextarea"placeholder="Name"></textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

Since the requirements include multi-line support, I'd recommend setting the top and bottom padding i.e:

```
.textbox1 { 
    width: 440px;
    height:6px;
    padding: 30px 5px;
}
```

```css
.textbox1 { 
    width: 440px;
    height:60px;
    padding: 30px 5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textbox1"name="mytextarea"placeholder="Name"></textarea>
```

Comment: @AbrarJahin I did & put a link that you can try.

Comment: I left out the majority of the code to make it simpler but when i do that it just increases the textbox size like this - https://jsfiddle.net/hb4wqsep/

Comment: Considering an example of a 600px height textbox your solution would be [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L2uLo0fe/)? Seems a little bit ugly to me, if the user want to enter some text...

Comment: Ok it had to do with the height property which my code didn't have. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt you're correct I didn't take the multi-line behavior into account

Answer (score 7):

This works for latest Firefox, IE/Edge, Chrome in pure CSS:

```
textarea { 
    width: 440px;
    height:600px; /* Note this is the same height as the placeholders line-height */
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    line-height:600px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Webkit */
    line-height:600px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE */
    line-height:600px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndou226o/). The key is to set the `height` of the textarea to the same `line-height` as the placeholder.

Sadly `vertical-align: middle;` seems not to be supported yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use `padding`, as `line height` will not work over multiple lines.

Additionally, make sure to take into account the line height / font size when calculating your padding.

Comment: Both `padding` and `line height` look not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not exactly what you want, But try to look ..

To center it vertically, I multiplied the height of the element to `7.5%` and make it line-height.

```
.textbox1{
width: 440px;
height:100px;
line-height: calc(100 * 7.5%);
}
.textbox1:focus{
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

Check it here. [pure CSS jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uznfn5t6/5/)

*Note: CSS3 calc() function only works on modern browsers. You can manually change/calculate the line-height if you want it to work on older browsers.*

or you really have to use jQuery

I made a help of jQuery here [jQuery jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uznfn5t6/6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.textbox1 { 
    width: 440px;
    height:70px
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
   line-height:70px;
   text-align: center; 
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   line-height:70px;
   text-align: center; 
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
   line-height:70px;
   text-align: center; 
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
   line-height:70px;
   text-align: center; 
}
```

You can check here [CSS jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/igweze/m750vqLu/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternate solution - you could set the rows to an odd number and add half the rows rounded down in line feed characters to put the placeholder in the middle...

```css
.textbox1 { 
  width: 440px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textbox1"name="mytextarea"placeholder="&#10;Name" rows=3></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="example" onFocus={onFocus} onBlur={outFocus} />
<label className={styles.Teaxarea_label}>Label</label>
```

and then you have those functions:

```
const outFocus = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value !== '') {
      event.target.nextSibling.style = "display:none;"
    }
    else {
      event.target.nextSibling.style = "display:block;"
    }
  }
  const onFocus = (event) => {
    event.target.nextSibling.style = "display:none;"
  }
```

CSS:

```
.Teaxarea_label{
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
}

textarea {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve on the padding answers, here is a way to guarantee calculations that center it. This works better than line-height for multiple lines, but it still means that once the user enters multiple lines of text, there will now be overflow to scroll, rendering the centering essentially useless

```
.textbox1 {
  --title-modal--textarea--height: 100px;
  /* font-size variable for calculations cannot be em, otherwise calculations become doubly-dependent on font-size */
  --title-modal--textarea--font-size: 1rem;
  --title-modal--textarea--line-height: 1.5;

  height: var(--title-modal--textarea--height) !important;
  font-size: var(--title-modal--textarea--font-size);
  line-height: var(--title-modal--textarea--line-height);

  padding-top: calc((var(--title-modal--textarea--height) - (var(--title-modal--textarea--line-height) * var(--title-modal--textarea--font-size)))/2);

  /* I used these to make sure the border doesn't take away from the height, */
  /* affecting the padding calculation, */
  /* but you could similarly turn them into variables and subtract */
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `line-height` property to make the placeholder vertically centered.

Comment: When answering an older question with existing answers it is helpful to explain why your answer differs from the existing answers. Formatting is also important, as this answer is formatted as all code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use absolutely positioned placeholder:

```css
textarea::placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Check this [example](https://codepen.io/MegaCasper/pen/ZEoJGdy)