# Safari input placeholder vertical alignment offset issue for smaller font

Tags: css, safari

In safari when you make the placeholder font smaller than the input's set size it vertically aligns to the top. Is there a way to center it to be in the middle of the input?

[image]

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193459/how-do-i-vertically-align-placeholder-text-in-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193459/how-do-i-vertically-align-placeholder-text-in-textarea)

Comment: that don't work